# how do i add in database values when duplicating In PPT

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Trying to duplicate slide 1 - 4 which will pull data from my database into shape 1 and 2

But i am getting a error : Method of 'Item' of object 'Shapes' Failed

New to Power point vba coding. I do not really understand why i am getting this error.

If i duplicate only slide 1 and without the array it works fine but i need to duplicate it in sets of slide 1 - 4. Is there a way to do this? or i have to find another way to do it

current code:

```
 Do Until rs.EOF
     Dim myPres As Presentation
Dim mySlide As SlideRange
Set myPres = ActivePresentation
Dim sldRng As PowerPoint.SlideRange
Set sldRng = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(1, 2, 3, 4)).Duplicate
sldRng.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = rs.Fields("SeqNo").Value
sldRng.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange = rs.Fields("SeqData").Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the line that throws the error, no?

> > sldRng.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = rs.Fields("SeqNo").Value

A sliderange contains slides; the slides themselves contain shapes, so you need to reference an individual slide from the sliderange, and then the shapes collection on just that slide:

```
sldRng(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = rs.Fields("SeqNo").Value
```

Or more likely:

```
Dim x as Long
For x = 1 to sldRng.Count
   sldRng(x).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = rs.Fields("SeqNo").Value
Next
```